# Show navigation after hide in android

Tags: java, android, navigation

I hide the navigation bar.
With the following code:

```
            View v = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                );
```

Now I want to return Navigation Bar
How can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show Navigation Bar on Android KitKat after hiding it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534080/show-navigation-bar-on-android-kitkat-after-hiding-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use code from official docs [Immersive](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

```
// This snippet hides the system bars.
private void hideSystemUI() {
  // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
  // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
  // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
  mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}

// This snippet shows the system bars. It does this by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
private void showSystemUI() {
  mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```